# Select for update query: Lock wait timeout exceeded error

Tags: python, mysql, django, select, locking

To avoid race conditions, I need to use `select for update` functionality while querying database so that it locks the row until the end of the transaction. Since select_for_update query is not present in Django 1.3, I have done a workaround it by using a class method which returns query sets by doing a raw sql query.

```
#models.py
class AccountDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    amount = models.IntegerField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_locked_for_update(cls,userid):
        accounts = cls.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM b2b_accountdetails WHERE user_id ="+str(userid)+" FOR UPDATE")
        return accounts[0]
```

This is how it's used in views.

```
account = AccountDetails.get_locked_for_update(userid)
account.amount = account.amount - fare
account.save()
```

On the last line I'm getting this error:
`OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')`

In dbshell, after running the `save()` line:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db     | Command | Time | State    | Info                                                                                                |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  51 | root | localhost | dbname | Query   |    0 | NULL     | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                                                               |
| 767 | root | localhost | dbname | Sleep   |   59 |          | NULL                                                                                                |
| 768 | root | localhost | dbname | Query   |   49 | Updating | UPDATE `b2b_accountdetails` SET `user_id` = 1, `amount` = 68906 WHERE `appname_accountdetails`.`id` = 1 |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

According to my understanding the lock should be released on the first data-altering query like update, delete etc.

But the `save()` statement is getting blocked and is kept on wait. Any idea why this is happening? What I think is when I'm calling `account.save()` it's not picking up the previous transaction started by select for update query.

Am I missing something obvious? Kindly help.

Comment: Are you using TransactionMiddleware? Does this problem occur in the context of an HTTP request?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides No I'm not using TransactionMiddleware. Yes it occurs in the context of an HTTP request, but not only in the context of HTTP request. The same error comes when I run the code from django shell.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving Django to its default autocommit-like behaviour for such an operation can easily lead to several kinds of errors (not locking the database at all could easily be another outcome); the details probably depend on the RDBMS and/or Django database driver for that particular RDBMS. It would be better to use [`@commit_on_success` or `@commit_manually` or `TransactionMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: I tried both methods, but it's not working. Please see my updated question. When I do `account.save()` a new thread is created. Hence it is blocked, as the previous thread has already locked the row.

Comment: Just to make certain: You tried `@commit_manually` to decorate the function that contains `account.save()`?

Comment: Yes I moved the part from select query to save to another function and applied the decorator on that function only, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think some other thread is holding a record lock on some record for too long, and your thread is being timed out this a problem specific to MYSQL which does not support nowait.

You can set higher value for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` and restart mysql

Comment: No I think I can safely rule out the possibility of any other thread holding a record. Because even when I kill all threads shown in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` this problem occurs. However, this debugging confirmed my initial guess: My select query and update query are running on two different threads. I will update this finding in my question.